# How to create a Foreign Key with "ON UPDATE CASCADE" on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

In MS SQL Server it is possible to create a foreign key with *ON UPDATE CASCADE* option, so whenever you update one of the columns in the primary key, the foreign keys in other tables will also be update by the DBMS.

So, how to do it in Oracle?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle does not allow a Foreign Key constraint with “ON UPDATE CASCADE”.

Here are a couple of options you have.

Create the Foreign Key, and create an “On Update” trigger. 
Make use of the package below (needs to be installed in the db).

http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html

Let me know if you have additional questions or need more information.

Comment: The Post is old to comment but I see a dead [URL](http://asktom.oracle.com/tkyte/update%5Fcascade/index.html). Being inquisitive here; If anyone happens to know the updated URL, pls. let us know.

Comment: @hiFI The post at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034 may contain the same information.

Comment: As usual, link is dead and no code given in answer, just hints...

Answer (score 2):

Would a database [trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/triggers.htm#g22503) do the job for you ?

Here is the [Oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#i13162) on the subject of Data Integrity for 11g (just incase you were interested).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use on update cascade, but you can create a trigger that will resolve the issue:

```
create table tab1(
pk int PRIMARY KEY,
aa int);

create table tab2(
pk int PRIMARY KEY,
tab1_pk int,
FOREIGN KEY(tab1_pk) REFERENCES tab1(pk));

------------------------------------------

create or replace trigger tab1_pkUpdate
    after update of pk on tab1
    for each row
 begin
    update tab2 s
    set s.tab1_pk = :new.pk
    where s.tab1_pk = :old.pk;
end;
/
```