# Create constraint alter table invalid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, constraints

I had to modify an existing constraint so it would cascade updates and deletes.
To do this I first removed the constraint and was planning on adding it (through an ALTER TABLE) but this fails.

When I commit the query below it gives me the error '`ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option`':

```
ALTER TABLE 
    PARAM 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
    FK_PARAM_PORTLET FOREIGN KEY (PORTLETID) 
REFERENCES PORTLET(ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Any idea what it could be? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in foreign keys.

Have a look at this question for tips: [How to create a Foreign Key with "ON UPDATE CASCADE" on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289877/how-to-create-a-foreign-key-with-on-update-cascade-on-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE CASCADE is not supported in Oracle. You will need to manage this via triggers.

Check [Oracle statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#sthref3088):

> Referential integrity constraints can specify particular actions to be
>   performed on the dependent rows in a child table if a referenced
>   parent key value is modified. The referential actions supported by the
>   FOREIGN KEY integrity constraints of Oracle are UPDATE and DELETE NO
>   ACTION, and DELETE CASCADE.